# Formula to check if one cell is within a range between two cells

Tags: google-sheets, formula, array-formulas

I'm trying to search through two columns with a  given value. For example:

A(values)
0-2
3-4
5-6
7-8
9-10

B
275
285
295
305
330

now say I have `3` as a given value. I would like to compare it with the range of values in A so in a logical sense it would fall under 3-4 and return `285`.
 I think Vlookup would take part ... maybe an if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this formula work as you want:

`=LOOKUP(3,ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(LEFT(FILTER(A:A,LEN(A:A)),SEARCH("-",FILTER(A:A,LEN(A:A)))-1))),FILTER(B:B,LEN(B:B)))`

Answer (score 1):

It may be simpler to change your `A` values and use a formula like:

```
=vlookup(D1,A:B,2)
```

[image]

In which case any value greater than 9 would also return `330` (unless say an IF clause precludes that).

[vlookup](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318) without a fourth parameter makes inexact matches (as well as exact) and when the first column of the lookup range is sorted ascending will chose the match appropriate to the highest value that is less than the search_key.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, if you use 'closed ranges' you can try something like:

```
=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP("3", {REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A6, "(\d+)-"), B2:B6}, 2, 1))
```